# How to change default path in Mojolicious controller

Tags: gnuplot, mojolicious

In my Mojolicious app, I am embedding a SVG file that was generated from gnuplot. The problem is that gnuplot ignores jsdir for grid.png and leaves it as a relative path.

```
  <image x='10' y='274' width='16' height='16' xlink:href='grid.png'
    onclick='gnuplot_svg.toggleGrid();'/>
```

This causes Mojolicious to come up with a URL to the image. In my case, I want to access this file from the public/ directory, but my controller wants to find it related to its path.

```
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.46569] [28105] [debug] GET "/reports/grid.png" (e9f0c2a8)
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.46596] [28105] [debug] Routing to controller "WebLOC::Controller::Auth" and action "check"
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.46632] [28105] [debug] Routing to controller "WebLOC::Controller::Reports" and action "grid"
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.46637] [28105] [debug] Action not found in controller
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.46658] [28105] [debug] Template "reports/grid.png.ep" not found
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.46679] [28105] [debug] Template "not_found.development.png.ep" not found
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.46696] [28105] [debug] Template "not_found.png.ep" not found
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.46713] [28105] [debug] Template "not_found.development.html.ep" not found
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.46729] [28105] [debug] Template "not_found.html.ep" not found
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.46739] [28105] [debug] Rendering cached template "mojo/debug.html.ep"
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.46851] [28105] [debug] Rendering cached template "mojo/menubar.html.ep"
[2019-04-08 10:19:21.47419] [28105] [debug] 404 Not Found (0.008486s, 117.841/s)
```

How can I have Mojolicious GET "/grid.png", rather than "/reports/grid.png"?

Comment: Interesting. I assumed this was an easy answer that I just wasn't finding in the massive Mojolicious documentation. Oh, well. I "resolved" this by going back to pursuing the canvas (HTML5) terminal in gnuplot. It seems to be a better solution for me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really related to Mojolicious but to XML/HTML. The path "grid.png" in XML will be interpreted relative to the current URL path. If it is in your root, you want the path "/grid.png" which is domain-relative. You may need to make use of the [url_for](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Plugin/DefaultHelpers#url_for) helper if your website is not deployed as the domain root.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't help my situation. The problem is, right or wrong, that gnuplot is generating this href. I don't have much control over it. If I was generating the XML, it could easily be fixed.